# spring.metrics.export.statsd.prefix on Spring boot 2.1.6

Tags: spring-boot, statsd

On spring boot 2.1.6 they change the configuration of statsd in the properties files.

so

```
spring.metrics.export.statsd.host=localhost
spring.metrics.export.statsd.port=8125
```

changed to

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.host=localhost
management.metrics.export.statsd.port=8125
```

but there is no

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.prefix=myapp
```

is there any equivalent way to get the same results of

```
spring.metrics.export.statsd.prefix=myapp
```

Comment: Have u got answer to this question? can you please let me here?

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer is, the prefix for the statsd has been removed in the micrometer->statsd. We need to append the prefix by ourselves for the metrics we need to send to statsd from code.

And for now, it is sending metrics to statsd -> graphite.
Note: Append it to the builder method of counter and gauges.

Comment: Can you please share a code example of how to do that?

Comment: Append your prefix where you are adding your counter / guage name
 (prefix + <namingConvention> + counterName)